# Nearby Friends updating from wrong phone

Tags: facebook

If I sign into Facebook via someone else's cell phone and then turn on my "Nearby Friends" and send out a notice to show my precise location until I choose to stop will it update later when I sign on from my cell?

My friend and I decided to share locations. She did not have her cell so she used her mother's to sign into her Facebook account and turned on "nearby friends" and then sent me a notification to share precise location until "you choose to stop". I did the same but from my cell.  Now I only get the feed from when she used her Mom's cell and it does not update though she has signed into Facebook from her cell since.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not update. She has to activate it from her cell also, and for better work after activation, restart FB app.

The system uses GPS and triangulation between cellphone towers to get your location. It then produces a map with all your "nearby friends" on it, as long as they too have enabled their precise location.

Sharing your location with Nearby Friends goes two ways -­‐-­‐ you and your friends both have to turn on Nearby Friends and choose to share with each other to see when you're nearby. Your friends will only be able to see that you're nearby if you share this info with them and vice versa.